# Is there a way to add a Network interface to a Virtual Machine of another resource group in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I already have a resource group in azure that has a virtual machine and it is associated with a network interface to connect to a vnet in that group.

```
resource-group-1
 -> virtual machine
 -> network interface
 -> vnet
 -> other things ...
```

But now i created a second resource group which will have some resources and a vnet. I want to use for now, the same virtual machine that exists on `resource-group-1`, so i created a network interface there:

```
resource-group-2
 -> network interface 2
 -> vnet 2
```

Now i want to connect the network interface 2 of `resource-group-1` to the virtual machine in `resource-group-2`.

I already tried, like the documentation says to stop the VM and going to `Settings`, `Networking` and `Attach network interface`, but i don't seem to be able to select anything useful there.

It seems that some time ago, this changes could only be done through powershell.
Another thing i saw is that we cannot change the vnet when adding a new nic to a VM. This might not be possible at all?

Currently, i guess the following options might make this possible

- Find a way to change the VNET of the VM, which will make it stop working with the old VNET.
- Create an equal VM with a snapshot for the new VNET.
- Connect the two VNETs and probably it will magically work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to add a new network interface that exists in the different VNet from the network interface currently attached to the VM to an existing VM. You can not add two NICs in different VNets to the same Azure VM. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-vm#add-a-network-interface-to-an-existing-vm).

If you want to move your azure VM and its NIC to another resource group, a simple way is to [move a VM to another resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/move-vm). Read [supported moving resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftcompute).

[image]

In addition, there is a [Step-by-Step PowerShell Guide](https://www.rebeladmin.com/2019/12/step-step-guide-move-azure-vm-different-resource-group-powershell-guide/): How to Move Azure VM to a different Resource Group?

Comment: thanks for the answer. What about peering the two vnets? is there a way to connect to the VM that way?

Comment: What is your purpose？A vm only could deploy in a vnet but can access another vm in another vnet.

Comment: The purpose is that i want to keep the VM on the same VNET it already is because it is still needed, but to be able to access it on another VNET. I've peered the 2 VNETs, i guess this way the VM will be accessible to resource on the second VNET